# Error while installing netbeans

Tags: software-installation, netbeans

I tried to install NetBeans 7.2 from a downloaded `.sh` file, but experienced problems. Here's text from the Terminal, which shows what I did and what happened:

```
hridesh@ubuntu:~$ cd Desktop/
hridesh@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cd full\ netbeans\ 7.2\ for\ linux\ in\ .sh\ format/
hridesh@ubuntu:~/Desktop/full netbeans 7.2 for linux in .sh format$ chmod +x netbeans-7.1.2-ml-linux.sh
hridesh@ubuntu:~/Desktop/full netbeans 7.2 for linux in .sh format$ ./netbeans-7.1.2-ml-linux.sh
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Installer file /home/hridesh/Desktop/full seems to be corrupted
```

Why does the message `Installer file /home/hridesh/Desktop/full seems to be corrupted` appear? Is this file actually corrupted or something else going wrong?

Comment: Did you solved your issue?

Comment: yes i solved my issue..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setup showed this error

```
Installer file /home/hridesh/Desktop/full seems to be corrupted
```

Since the full path being used is "home/hridesh/Desktop/full netbeans 7.2 for linux in .sh format" it would seem that the installer is having problem with such a *complex* folder name.

Renaming the folder "full netbeans 7.2 for linux in .sh format" to something simple like "netbeans_installer" should solve the problem the installer is reporting.

```
cd Desktop
mv full\ netbeans\ 7.2\ for\ linux\ in\ .sh\ format netbeans_installer
cd netbeans_installer
./netbeans-7.1.2-ml-linux.sh
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
 sudo ./netbeans-7.1.2-ml-linux.sh
```

Comment: If installing NetBeans globally for systemwide use (rather than for a single user), running the installer as `root` may help, but doing so is irrelevant to *this* problem. In *this* problem, the installer script runs but doesn't get far enough to install anything because it cannot access some file (perhaps a file it has just created, perhaps itself to read binary data out) in the directory where it resides. Furthermore, if installing NetBeans to be run and maintained by a single-user without affecting other users, the installer should *not* be run with `sudo`.

Comment: -1 `sudo` is not the magical solution. Do not suggest it in cases like this, where the installation can be done in the user's home directory.

Answer (score -2):

Should be: `sh netbeans-7.1.2-ml-linux.sh`

Comment: The script was able to start running the first time without being run that way -- `./` syntax was sufficient. This means that the script contains a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) line at the beginning, which means it's intended to be run with `./` syntax and doesn't need to be run by explicitly invoking `sh`. Furthermore, this is totally unrelated to the error message which was given *once the script had already started running*.